# What is more appropriate way of managing Users, their roles, modules and permission?

Tags: java, sql, spring, database

We have a web application where we need to create functionality to manage users, roles , modules and their permissions.

Below is the design we have created. can anyone Let me know if it is proper way of implementing such functionality?

User table will have two columns as follows

1) Id 
2) Name

Role table will have Role Id and role name.

A user can have multiple roles hence, we will have a user role reference table which will have user id and role id.

Role can be Admin, User, Moderator etc.

There can be lots of modules like Country , States, Orders, Divisions etc.

Each role will have access to certain modules like Admin will have access to all modules.

User will have access to few modules like Order only and so on.

So for this we have a separate static Modules table which will have module id and name.

We will have another Role Module reference  table which will hold the information of which role have access to which modules.

Again, each user will have some roles and thus will have access to certain modules.

Now access to this modules is also based on permissions.

Like User will have only read permissions on States and Country i.e. he can only view the details.

Admin will have write permissions on states and country so that he can add, edit and delete them.

So, how do i go about implementing/designing this whole functionality in java?

Comment: I would recomend you to use http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: @heldt Spring security is a great framework but we want to have this function inbuilt in our application so that it is more customizable. More ever we will have super admins who will be doing the work of managing this function :(

Comment: Do you need to have different roles in different States for example? Or if they are an admin in one state will they be an admin in all states?

Comment: @Ben States is just one of the module. Module can be anything like Order, Divisions, Branches etc. Basically modules refers to the menus available to the user. If a user has access to say module A, he will see the link for the module A in menu. Clicking on menu will open listing page for the Module and will have regular CRUD for that Module like add/edit/delete/listing States (or any other module). User will see add/edit/delete if he has write permission for module or simple view page if he has only read permission on that module.

Comment: No one got any solutions or ideas with which we can move forward ? :-(

Comment: You could consider putting both roles and permissions into hierarchies.  You'll need to maintain these hierarcies but maintainance of granular permissions for users (and roles) becomes easier as you just have to map them to the appropriate points in the trees rather than creating many entries in the reference tables.

Comment: @anything what did you ended up using ? Are there any advances since then ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tables:

- User (userID PK, name, etc...)
- Role (roleID PK, name UQ, etc...)
- UserRole (userID, roleID, PK(userID, roleID) dategranted etc...)
- Module (moduleID PK, name UQ, etc...)
- RoleModuleAccess (roleID, moduleID, PK(roleID, moduleID), accessFlags)

To find out the access a user `@userID` has in a module `@moduleID`:

```
select accessFlags
from RoleModuleAccess rma 
    inner join UserRole ur on ur.roleID = rma.roleID
where rma.moduleID = @moduleID and ur.userID = @userID
```

Comment: This looks great. What will be the best possible way of UI for this in the front end?

Comment: Assuming there are many more users than roles, show the list of roles against the user. If there are many roles, show only those granted, and give UI to add to the list. If there are few roles, show checkboxes.

Same for RoleModuleAccess - either show the list against the module or against the role, whichever makes most sense.

Comment: Are there any open-source implementations that I can directly integrate in my web-app ?